# Sliding Contact Form Re-Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I want to re-position my sliding contact form. I have seen a tutorial in the net.. but it's positioned in the right. When clicked it slides to the left..

Here is the [DEMO](http://www.mrova.com/feedbackForm/index.html) of the tutorial

So instead of having it in the right side.. I want to reposition in the bottom right of the screen. Instead of sliding left.. it will slide up when the button is clicked. I'm not very good in jQuery yet . Help

here is the code:

HTML:::

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Feedback Form Demo</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Files For mRova Feedback Form [Dependency: jQuery] -->
    <script src="mrova-feedback-form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mrova-feedback-form.css" type="text/css"/>
    <!-- END -->

    <!-- Just For Demo -->
    <style type="text/css">
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, tahoma, verdana, sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    color: #333;
}
</style>
    <!-- END -->
    </head>
    <body>
<h1>Free Feedback Form</h1>

<!--Feedback Form HTML START -->
<div id="mrova-feedback">
      <div id="mrova-contact-thankyou" style="display: none;"> Thank you.  We'hv received your feedback. </div>
      <div id="mrova-form">
    <form id="mrova-contactform" action="#" method="post">
          <ul >
        <li>
              <label for="mrova-name">Your Name*</label>
              <input type="text" name="mrova-name" class="required" id="mrova-name" value="">
            </li>
        <li>
              <label for="mrova-email">Email*</label>
              <input type="text" name="mrova-email" class="required" id="mrova-email" value="">
            </li>
        <li>
              <label for="mrova-message">Message*</label>
              <textarea class="required" id="mrova-message" name="mrova-message"  rows="8" cols="30"></textarea>
            </li>
      </ul>
          <input type="submit" value="Send" id="mrova-sendbutton" name="mrova-sendbutton">
        </form>
  </div>
      <div id="mrova-img-control"></div>
    </div>
<!-- Feedback Form HTML END -->

</body>
</html>
```

CSS::

```
label {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#mrova-feedback {
    display: hidden;
    width: 420px;
    position: fixed;
    right: -462px;
    border: 1px solid #3cb58c;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#mrova-contactform ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#mrova-contactform input, #mrova-contactform textarea {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#mrova-contactform ul li {
    list-style: none;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#mrova-img-control {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: -52px;
    width: 52px;
    background: transparent url('feedback_buttons/feedback.jpg');
    height: 168px;
}
#mrova-contactform #mrova-sendbutton {
    width: 60px;
    background: #db4f4a;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: none;
}
```

JS:::

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.vAlign = function() {
    return this.each(function(i){
    var h = $(this).height();
    var oh = $(this).outerHeight();
    var mt = (h + (oh - h)) / 2;    
    $(this).css("margin-top", "-" + mt + "px"); 
    $(this).css("top", "50%");
    }); 
};
$.fn.toggleClick = function(){
    var functions = arguments ;
    return this.click(function(){
            var iteration = $(this).data('iteration') || 0;
            functions[iteration].apply(this, arguments);
            iteration = (iteration + 1) % functions.length ;
            $(this).data('iteration', iteration);
    });
};
})(jQuery);
$(window).load(function() {
    //cache
    $img_control = $("#mrova-img-control");
    $mrova_feedback = $('#mrova-feedback');
    $mrova_contactform = $('#mrova-contactform');

    //setback to block state and vertical align to center
    $mrova_feedback.vAlign()
    .css({'display':'block','height':$mrova_feedback.outerHeight()});
    //Aligning feedback button to center with the parent div 

    $img_control.vAlign()
    //animate the form
    .toggleClick(function(){
        $mrova_feedback.animate({'right':'-2px'},1000);
    }, function(){
        $mrova_feedback.animate({'right':'-'+$mrova_feedback.outerWidth()},1000);
    });

    //Form handling
    $('#mrova-sendbutton').click( function() {
                var url = 'send.php';
                var error = 0;



                $('.required', $mrova_contactform).each(function(i) {
                    if($(this).val() === '') {
                        error++;
                    }
                });
                // each
                if(error > 0) {
                    alert('Please fill in all the mandatory fields. Mandatory fields are marked with an asterisk *.');
                } else {
                    $str = $mrova_contactform.serialize();

                    //submit the form
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "GET",
                        url : url,
                        data : $str,
                        success : function(data) {

                            if(data == 'success') {
                                // show thank you
                                $('#mrova-contact-thankyou').show();
                                $mrova_contactform.hide();
                            } else {
                                alert('Unable to send your message. Please try again.');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    //$.ajax

                }
                return false;
            });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me: 
In your css file:

```
#mrova-feedback {
    display: hidden;
    width: 420px;
    position: fixed;
    left: -462px;
    border: 1px solid #3cb58c;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#mrova-img-control {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: -52px;
    width: 52px;
    background: transparent url('feedback_buttons/feedback.jpg');
    height: 168px;
}
```

Is change right for left, basicly...

In your js file:

```
$img_control.vAlign()
//animate the form
.toggleClick(function(){
    $mrova_feedback.animate({'left':'-2px'},1000);
}, function(){
    $mrova_feedback.animate({'left':'-'+$mrova_feedback.outerWidth()},1000);
});
```

Comment: I want to position it in the "Lower Right part of the Screen" not in the left side.

Comment: I´m sorry. In css, add "bottom: 0" to #mrova-feedback

Comment: And delete this in js:
//setback to block state and vertical align to center
//$mrova_feedback.vAlign()
//.css({'display':'block','height':$mrova_feedback.outerHeight()});
//Aligning feedback button to center with the parent div

Comment: I want it to slidetoggle from bottom to top.